# ASP.NET Core 3.1 upgrade issue

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to upgrade my application to ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I am getting the below error when I am trying to Resolves a type using the type activator cache, 
Below is the sample code,

The TypeActivatorCache isnt supported in ASP.NET Core 3.1 anymore and hence I have used the below code to replicate what it does in a nutshell, **https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/TypeActivatorCache.cs**

```
private TInstance CreateInstance<TInstance>(
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            Type implementationType)
        {
            if (serviceProvider == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
            }

            if (implementationType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(implementationType));
            }

            var createFactory = _typeActivatorCache.GetOrAdd(implementationType, _createFactory);
            return (TInstance)createFactory(serviceProvider, arguments: null);
        }
```

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions'.'

Any help would be much appreciated,

Comment: I've never worked with TypeActivatorCache but have you checked, that the required dependencies are available? I think IHostingEnvironment is new in dotnet core 3 (it was something like IWebhostingEnvironment before.)

Comment: Could you please show what you're trying to do and the related code? Maybe this is a X-Y problem. Why do you need `TypeActivatorCache`?